# Can't show xml child nodes under their parent category node using php?

Tags: php, xml

I know I might have asked a silly question but am really eager to good PHP developer, so any way, regarding my question:

I need the following Structure

> **Cat1**   item1   item2
>   **Cat2**   item21   item22
>   etc....

My XML Structure is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List>
    <category name="cat1" dispName="First Category" catCode="FC1">
        <item itmCode="item1">
            <name>item 1</name>
            <img>path to image 1</img>
        </item>
        <item itmCode="item2">
            <name>item 2</name>
            <img>path to image 2</img>
        </item>
    </category>
    <category name="cat2" dispName="Second Category" catCode="SC2">
        <item itmCode="item21">
            <name>item 21</name>
            <img>path to image 21</img>
        </item>
        <item itmCode="item22">
            <name>item 22</name>
            <img>path to image 22</img>
        </item>
    </category>
</List>
```

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('items.xml') or die('Error: Cannot create Grouped Items');
foreach($xml->category as $cat){
    $currentCat=$cat['dispName'];
    $catName=$cat['name'];
    echo $catName.'<br/>';
    echo $currentCat.'<br/>';
    $itemsCount=3;
    $random = array_rand($xml->xpath('category'), 3);
    if(is_array($random) || is_object($random)){
        foreach ($random as $key){
            //here is the issue as am trying to get the child nodes of each of the category nodes from the above XML list
        }
    }else{echo '<br/>error<br/>';}
}
?>
```

what is best way to write a good high performing listing page where i will later have too many categories and each of them will have more than 30 items.

I really appreciate any help and suggestions are really appreciated as am working alone on this project (a family project) where am the developer - designer :)

Comment: Please specify what you want to accomplish. Your code seems far too complex to solve the problem you are describing on top.

Comment: Simply I need to list only x items from each category and write the category name on top of its items.

Comment: for more info i have a running page with what i need to view but its misbehaving currently
http://www.uistarter.com/css3icons/icons.php
currently am having the category and what i want is to list 3 items below each cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If items are grouped under category, as in your example XML, two simple foreach-loops do the trick:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x

foreach ($xml->category as $cat) {
    echo $cat['dispName'] . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($cat->item as $item) {
        echo $item->name . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Add a **counter** to limit items, use `break` to stop the inner `foreach` loop if counter = limit.

```
foreach ($xml->category as $cat) {
    echo $cat['dispName'] . PHP_EOL;
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($cat->item as $item) {
        echo $item->name . PHP_EOL;
        $count = $count + 1;
        if ($count == 3) break; 
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could `echo` the item only if counter < limit, but then the loop would continue to the last item in category, which will slow performance if you have large amounts of items.

See it in action: https://eval.in/533305

Comment: I really thank you so much for helping me out, and am having one more small question if applicable i want to get random 3 items, is it possible to be done??

Comment: I figured out how to get 3 random items each time:
    `$icons=array();`  
    `foreach($cat->icon as $icon){`  
        `$icons[] = $case;`  
    `}`  
    `shuffle($icons);`